Проблема кеширования на сервере cloudflare
Доподлинно не совсем понятно как это происходит но постараюсь объяснить ситуацию максимально подробно.
По механике процесса всё должно быть просто. Мы запрашиваем файл страницы у cloudflare, он смотрит её в кеше, проверяет не было ли обновлений и отдает нам либо от сервера либо от кеша. Но пришлось с такой ситуацией столкнуться когда после сборки перестала работать часть сайта. При разборе всех нюансов оказалось, что при запросе чанка который отвечает за эту страницу происходит магия и вместо js нам в файле приходит содержимое index.html предыдущей сборки. Hash файлов был обновлен, запрос выполнялся по адресу и названию именно нового файла js, а ответ от CDN пришел почему index.html предыдущей версии сборки.
Может кто то сталкивался с подобным? Регулярность повторения полный рандом, какой раздел отключится тоже случайность, может вообще весь сайт лечь. Бывает по 3 месяца перерыв, бывает месяц.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

А почему вы решили, что виноват именно cloudflare, а не, например, ваш криво настроенный сервер? Почему вы решили, что кеширование на стороне cloudflare вообще есть? Если вы вините кеширование, то почему не попробуете его отключить?

Для начала попробуйте сбросить кэш в cloudflare и при повторении проблемы подробнее рассказать что у вас установлено на сервере, может он кэширует и неправильно отдает файлы

Сброс кеша на cloudflare помогает, потому решил что дело в cloudflare, но как избежать подобного в будущем, как понять проблема в cloudflare или в сервере. К сожалению я фронтенд разработчик и не обладаю компетенцией в данном вопросе. Все кто обладает, скидывают проблему на сборку frontend, что мол webpack баговано собирает и отдает неверные hash файлов, поэтому запрос не верный. Мои аргументы игнорируются. Повторяется ошибка рандомно, поэтому буду ждать повторения.

Буду очень признателен за подробное объяснения. И может ли сервер отдать cloudflare неверные данные по корректному запросу?

@Тимур в Cloudflare можно снизить или вовсе убрать кэширование страниц. Либо настройте CI/CD с автоматическим сбросом кэша после сборки проекта. Это обычная практика при использовании подобных сервисов. Cloudflare автоматически кэширует страницы для более быстрой доставки контента в разные страны, это оптимальный вариант и вам после сборки нужно прожать одну кнопку для стабильной работы.
